# GeoNamesClient: How can I get city, state, country, region from a zip code? C#

Tags: c#, geonames

I'm using GeoNames, I know how to search FOR postal codes (`GeoNamesClient.SearchPostalCodes`) but I need the opposite, I need to get the city, state, and country associated with a specific postal code. How do I do this?

Comment: I was asking specifically for GeoNames

Comment: How are using this? Seems it should be asking for a username now. Reference: https://ngeo.codeplex.com/